# In SOLR, how can I query to find an indexed keyword inside a user provided search query?

Tags: search, solr, jetty, contains

I am running SOLR 3.6, and have documents that have tags indexed.  When a user enters a search phrase, I'd like to be able to find documents with tags contained inside that query.

E.g, a user searching for "Any document that has boats tagged" would match a document that had "boats" as a tag.

I know you can do wildcard searching, but I need the wildcards applied to the solr field, not the search query.

The MySQL equivalent to this would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `documents` WHERE "Any document that has boats tagged" LIKE 'CONCAT('%', `document`, '%');
```

So I need a SOLR factory that will allow this type of query:

```
*document*:"Any document that has boats tagged"
```

Answer (score 0):

If `tags` field in Solr is a multi-valued text field with LowerCaseFilterFactory during both index time and query time, then you can simply issue this query:

```
q=tags:(Super fast boats)
```

(I changed your example here.) That will give you the documents that have all the 3 tags first (if any), followed by documents that have 2 tags (if any) and then 1 tag.

This is assuming that in your schema.xml you got `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>`. If you have an AND instead, you need to delimit the words with `OR` like:

```
q=tags:(any OR document OR that OR has OR boats OR tagged)
```

(You may also want to use stemming for your tags and queries to match more tags, but that is something you need to experiment and decide.)

Comment: That's helpful, but what if the tags field can be multiple words.  So, a query for "Super fast boats" should match documents with tags "Super fast" and "fast boats"  but, it should not match documents with just "fast" tagged.

Comment: Then you will need to construct the Solr query before calling Solr like: `q=tags:(("super fast" OR "fast boats") AND -fast)`. That means your app knows all the tag names, which may not be feasible. An alternate approach will be to look at the scores of the returned documents (add the request param `fl=*,score` to see the score). The docs that matched maximum tags will have the highest score and the docs with only one tag match will be the lowest.